# restoring rman backed up files on windows machine

Tags: oracle10g, rman

I have rman backup database in oracle 10.2.0.1. I took this back up on linux machine. After backup is done, I have got 4 files for my database including log files etc. I copied those files on my windows machine. Their, on windows machine, I want to restore that backup. I just have those 4 files. How to do it? I am totally new to rman and database administrating things.

Answer (score 0):

With different OS platform, backup rman on Linux then restoring on Windows can't take place. Using Oracle datapump (expdp, impdp) instead.